# asp.net core weird issue

Tags: asp.net-core, static, field

I found a weird issue: the static field had not been assigned before reference it.
I create a filter class like this:

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public class ConfigChangedAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        private static DateTime lastConfig = DateTime.Now;
        private readonly ILogger<ConfigChangedAttribute> _logger;

        public ConfigChangedAttribute(ILogger<ConfigChangedAttribute> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _logger.LogInformation("ConfigChangedAttribute initialized");
        }

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            DateTime myConfigTime = context.HttpContext.Session.GetObject<DateTime>("configTime");

            if(myConfigTime.Ticks == 0)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation(context.ActionDescriptor.DisplayName + "  no configtime:" + DateTime.Now.ToString());
                context.HttpContext.Session.SetObject("configTime", DateTime.Now);
                return;
            }


            if(myConfigTime < lastConfig)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("myConfigTime:" + myConfigTime.ToString() + "     lastConfig:" + lastConfig.ToString());
                _logger.LogInformation(context.ActionDescriptor.DisplayName + " configtime changed.");
                context.HttpContext.Session.SetObject("configTime", DateTime.MinValue);
                context.Result =new UnauthorizedResult();
            }
        }

    }
```

I made a static flag configTime to record the start time, and it supposed to store the datetime when some config has been updated. and the flag will be evaluated on every request except the first request. On the first request, there is no request time has been stored in the session, so I  use the current datetime when the first request occurs. Because the OnActionExecuting method is an instance method, so the datetime got at this method should be bigger than the static field one, because the static field will be initialized before the first instance created.
But the result is myConfigTime < lastConfig is TRUE. What happened?
I also found how to resolve this issue, but I want to know this is a bug or I missed something.
Here is a solution:

```
        public ConfigChangedAttribute(ILogger<ConfigChangedAttribute> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _logger.LogInformation("ConfigChangedAttribute initialized:" + lastConfig); // refer it one time
        }
```

And this code is how I used it on Controller:

```
    [Authorize]
    [TypeFilter(typeof(ConfigChangedAttribute))]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
```

At last, the log also may be helpful:

```
2023-03-02 15:31:01,259 INFO  Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
2023-03-02 15:31:01,272 INFO  Hosting environment: Development
2023-03-02 15:31:01,273 INFO  Content root path: D:\algotag\AlgoTag
2023-03-02 15:31:06,056 WARN  Sensitive data logging is enabled. Log entries and exception messages may include sensitive application data; this mode should only be enabled during development.
2023-03-02 15:31:07,038 INFO  ConfigChangedAttribute initialized
2023-03-02 15:31:07,061 INFO  AlgoTag.Controllers.HomeController.Privacy (AlgoTag)  no configtime:2023/3/2 15:31:07
2023-03-02 15:31:08,635 INFO  ConfigChangedAttribute initialized
2023-03-02 15:31:08,658 INFO  myConfigTime:2023/3/2 15:31:07     lastConfig:2023/3/2 15:31:08
2023-03-02 15:31:08,660 INFO  AlgoTag.Controllers.HomeController.CompareTag (AlgoTag) configtime changed.
```

PS: I have not change the lastConfig yet at all.
Thank you.

Edit:2023/3/6
Thanks for Chen's answer.
I also made another example to check whether it is a static member issue or not:

```
    public class Holder
    {
        public static int IntVal = 0;
        public static DateTime DateTimeVal;
    }

    public class StaticDateTime
    {
        private static DateTime config = DateTime.Now;

        public StaticDateTime()
        {

        }

        public void configChanged()
        {
            DateTime d = Holder.DateTimeVal;
            if (d.Ticks == 0)
            {
                Holder.DateTimeVal = DateTime.Now;
                return;
            }

            if (d < config)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("config changed.");
            }
        }
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StaticDateTime sd = new StaticDateTime();
            sd.configChanged();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500);
            StaticDateTime sd2 = new StaticDateTime();
            sd2.configChanged();
            Console.WriteLine("press any key.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

And unfortunately, it seems it is not static member issue.

Comment: This issue is the same root cause of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75658985/net-5-0-vs-net-framework-4-6-different-behavior; please refer there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your `lastConfig` is a `static` variable.

The initial value setting item of the static field variable of the class corresponds to a assignment sequence. These assignments are executed according to the text order of the text that appear in the relevant classes.

If there is a static constructor in the class, the execution of the initial value setting item of the static field occurs before the static constructor is about to be executed.

Otherwise, the initial value setting item of the static field is executed before the static field of this class was used for the first time, but **the actual execution time depends on the specific implementation**.

So the value of `lastConfig` is actually the time you execute `if (myConfigtime <lastConfig)`.

There is no problem with your solution, but I recommend you to assign it in the constructor:

```
public ConfigChangedAttribute(ILogger<ConfigChangedAttribute> logger)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _logger.LogInformation("ConfigChangedAttribute initialized");
    lastConfig = DateTime.Now;
}
```

In addition, I noticed that you did not give value to `myConfigTime` after adding the `Session` called `configTime`. Therefore, the value of `myConfigTime` when you first entered will be `0001/1/1/1/1:00:00`, which will lead `myConfigTime <lastConfig` will always be established when the first enters.

Of course, I don’t know the logic of your controller, just a reminder...

Hope this can help you.

**Output:**

[image]

**Update:**

Did you add breakpoints while testing? This causes a delay, adds the current time to `config`, and causes the actual result to differ from the normal output. We recommend that the output results without adding breakpoints shall prevail.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, I add more test case, would you like to check it again?

Comment: Hi @Mike, The test results are the same, `d < config` is also true, I put the output above.

Comment: Hi @Chen, that is so weird, I have run the console app code in .net Framework 4.6 and VS2019, but I didn't get "config changed".  This make me struggle.

Comment: Hi @Mike, your title says `asp.net core` so I test with `.NET 6`.

Comment: I thought this should be the same whatever the .net core and .net framework, because this is the very basic logic. I am new to asp.net core. In .net framework, all the static field will be initialized when the class has been referenced first time.