# .net 5.0 VS .net framework 4.6 different behavior

Tags: c#, .net-5, .net-framework-version

Notes this code, when run it in .net framework 4.6, only get "press any key.", but can get "config changed." in .net 5.0, why?

```
    public class Holder
    {
        public static int IntVal = 0;
        public static DateTime DateTimeVal;
    }

    public class StaticDateTime
    {
        private static DateTime config = DateTime.Now;

        public StaticDateTime()
        {

        }

        public void configChanged()
        {
            DateTime d = Holder.DateTimeVal;
            if (d.Ticks == 0)
            {
                Holder.DateTimeVal = DateTime.Now;
                return;
            }

            if (d < config)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("config changed.");
            }
        }
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StaticDateTime sd = new StaticDateTime();
            sd.configChanged();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500);
            StaticDateTime sd2 = new StaticDateTime();
            sd2.configChanged();
            Console.WriteLine("press any key.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

in .net framework's logic, all the static members will be initialized at the first time when it is referenced: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members

> The program cannot specify exactly when the class is loaded. However, it is guaranteed to be loaded and to have its fields initialized and its static constructor called before the class is referenced for the first time in your program.

It seems this logic is not avalible in .net core, is there any official documents?

Comment: I've reproduced this - will look into the difference.

Comment: I am actually surprised this works in .NET core. Looks like the intialization of the static `config` property is suspended until it's actually needed, instead of initializing it before any other member. Moving the `config = DateTime.Now;` into a static constructor of the `StaticDateTime` makes it behave the same way in both (no message).

Comment: @WiktorZychla: It's not a property, it's a field. You don't need to *move* the initialization into a static constructor - it's the *presence* of a static constructor that makes the difference there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That quoted paragraph is slightly too loose. It's entirely possible to execute code in a method without initializing its containing class. If the class doesn't have a static constructor, class initialization *must* happen at some point before the first reference to a static field, and before the first instance is created - but it can happen at any point up until then.

Here's a somewhat simpler way of reproducing that:

```cs
using System;

class Program
{
    static int field = ReportInitialization();

    private static int ReportInitialization()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Field initializer called");
        return 5;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Before field reference");
        int f = field;
        Console.WriteLine($"Field value: {f}");
    }
}
```

In .NET 6.0 on my machine, this prints:

```
Before field reference
Field initializer called
Field value: 5
```

In .NET 4.6.2 on my machine, this prints:

```
Field initializer called
Before field reference
Field value: 5
```

If you add a static constructor (`static Program(){}`) then both have the same output as .NET 4.6.2 above.

The C# standard has a more precise phrasing. From [section 14.5.62](https://github.com/dotnet/csharpstandard/blob/draft-v7/standard/classes.md#14562-static-field-initialization):

> The static field variable initializers of a class correspond to a sequence of assignments that are executed in the textual order in which they appear in the class declaration (§14.5.6.1). Within a partial class, the meaning of “textual order” is specified by §14.5.6.1. If a static constructor (§14.12) exists in the class, execution of the static field initializers occurs immediately prior to executing that static constructor. Otherwise, the static field initializers are executed at an implementation-dependent time prior to the first use of a static field of that class.

[Section 14.12](https://github.com/dotnet/csharpstandard/blob/draft-v7/standard/classes.md#1412-static-constructors) on static constructors states:

> The static constructor for a closed class executes at most once in a given application domain. The execution of a static constructor is triggered by the first of the following events to occur within an application domain:
>
> - An instance of the class is created.
> - Any of the static members of the class are referenced.

Comment: "If you add a static constructor (static Program(){}) then both have the same output as .NET 4.6.2 above." is a bit weird, because technically, the line ´static int field = ReportInitialization();´  _generates_ the static constructor in the generated code.

Comment: @PMF: No, that generates a type initializer. They're not the same thing. (It's called `.cctor` in the IL, but it's not a static constructor...) And the C# language spec is only using C# terminology of course. The IL standard doesn't use the term "static constructor" at all as far as I can see. See https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/BeforeFieldInit for more about this (from a very long time ago)

Comment: The only difference is actually indeed that beforeFieldInit flag. The code of the cctor is exactly the same in both cases (well, except for an added nop for some weird reason). The article you link to exactly explains the problem. -- Since one should not normally have a side effect in an initializer/static constructor, the difference is normally negligible.